# W/Firestore: Stream closed with status: Status{code=INTERNAL, description=error in frame handler,

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I am using flutter firestore, it was working properly but suddenly this error came and stop writing operation

W/Firestore(25709): (24.4.0) [WriteStream]: (3513ff8) Stream closed with status: Status{code=INTERNAL, description=error in frame handler, cause=java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method getBuffer()Lokio/Buffer; in class Lokio/BufferedSource; or its super classes (declaration of 'okio.BufferedSource' appears in /data/app/~~G9c6fWlNC5LeVKO_bfdo8Q==/com.example.taafi_application_v1-WbGfHWKKjFunYoB6Qy7Syw==/base.apk!classes7.dex)
W/Firestore(25709):     at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpClientTransport$ClientFrameHandler.data(OkHttpClientTransport.java:1123)
W/Firestore(25709):     at io.grpc.okhttp.internal.framed.Http2$Reader.readData(Http2.java:234)
W/Firestore(25709):     at io.grpc.okhttp.internal.framed.Http2$Reader.nextFrame(Http2.java:147)
W/Firestore(25709):     at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpClientTransport$ClientFrameHandler.run(OkHttpClientTransport.java:1082)
W/Firestore(25709):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
W/Firestore(25709):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
W/Firestore(25709):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
W/Firestore(25709): }.

i try to upgrade the firestore,and flutter clean but nothing happend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this problem in my Flutter project when I added a dependency to google_ml_kit in my pubspec.yaml file. This issue is documented at  https://github.com/bharat-biradar/Google-Ml-Kit-plugin/issues/286. If you recently added some dependencies in your pubspec.yaml file, you might try temporarily removing them to see if the problem goes away.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to place the below code inside your build.gradle app level above the dependencies tag.

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
        force 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.5'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dependency problem with `google_ml_kit`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issues. I followed some of the instructions but I don't know which exactly works.

No1. Uninstall old version
no2. flutter clean
no3. flutter pub cache repair
no3. flutter pub upgrade outdated_package

Now I add both dependency. Following https://pub.dev/packages/google_mlkit_text_recognition

dependencies {
// Add language package you need to use
implementation 'com.google.mlkit:text-recognition-chinese:16.0.0-beta6'
implementation 'com.google.mlkit:text-recognition-devanagari:16.0.0-beta6'
implementation 'com.google.mlkit:text-recognition-japanese:16.0.0-beta6'
implementation 'com.google.mlkit:text-recognition-korean:16.0.0-beta6'
}

After that its work fine